# Styling Instagram feed - are the logo or account identification required?

Tags: instagram

I'm working on providing styled Instagram feeds for our users on their web sites. Some people want there to be no indication that the gallery feed on their site is coming from Instagram. Looking at the asset usage guidelines though, it seems like Instagram says that you have to include something to indicate that it is from Instagram.

When I look at something like a Squarespace Instagram feed, I see no indication (on the public-facing side on my site) that a gallery I set up on the backend to be an Instagram feed is from Instagram.

https://help.instagram.com/304689166306603

I am assuming Instagram's asset guidelines only mean that *if* you want to use their assets, this is how, but not that those assets are *required*. Anyone know for sure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you seem to be asking for legal advice rather than asking a specific programming question.

Comment: Ahhh true. The Instagram help page links here for API questions but you are right I suppose this more more legal than technical. Sincere apologies.